# Bulk insert using sql server, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I need to insert the bulk data into MS SQLServer (approximately 2lac records) from excel or csv format file using asp.net C# web application.

My problem :

It throws out of memory exception.

So, I need to fix the issue from asp.net but NOT THROUGH SQLSERVER.

When I tried the bulk data insert/Update at the SQLServer it works fine. But when I tried to do the same process using the ASP.NET the system throws "Out of Memory Exception"

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Thanks 
Vadivelu

Comment: How are you uploading the excel / csv file in the first place? I presume that a xls / csv file with 200,000 records could potentially be quite big in size depending on the individual size of each record

Answer (score 2):

See some resources:

- [Bulk Insert into SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=323&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
- [Video: Using SqlBulkCopy to Bulk Insert Data between SQL Server Tables](http://aspalliance.com/1676)